# How to install Gitlab on OS X lion server 10.8.5

Tags: macos, osx-lion, gitlab

Can someone tell me if it is possible to install Gitlab on OSX Lion Server 10.8.5 or any procedure to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could this be of any help. It does not target your version number exactly, but the procedure may be similar:

From makebetterthings.com: http://www.makebetterthings.com/git/install-gitlab-5-3-on-mac-os-x-server-10-8-4/

Comment: Tried and get error when typing "rails S -e production -p 8080".  Is not under Git user to launch this command ? ie: sudo -u git rails ...  I am beginner and never used ruby, gitlab,  etc; just try to install it.